# Repeatedly performing an action while button is clicked

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I have a button that runs a code that changes the background to a random color on each click. I would also like to give the user the ability to keep on changing the background color as long as the button is clicked. I believe that the onTouchListener will be my best bet. However, I do not now how to implement the code correctly.

I tried on the onLongClickListener but found out that onLongClickListener doesn't work that way.

Incomplete code for the onTouchListener (randomize is the name of my button):

```
randomize.setOnTouchListener(new Button.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
     if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        // start the thread
        return true;
     } else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
       // stop the thread
       return true;
     }
     return false;
   }
});
```

So, what I aim to be able to do is to keep on pressing the button and having the background continuously change while still preserving the onclick method of the button. So, onclick changes the background once and continuous click changes the background continuously.

Thank you so much folks :)

Ps. I'm just a beginner to android so I'm sorry if I do not know much. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   btn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            count++;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Integer.toString(count) , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hello there. Thank you so much. I adapted your code, but it only works if my finger keeps on moving while touching the button. Is there any way for the action to be performed without having to keep on moving my finger while it is on the button? :)

Comment: No keep your finger still. It works fine I have tested it.

Comment: It works in the sense that when I hold the button, the number in the Toast increases. However, when I leave the button and touch any other part of the screen, the Toast is still displaying the number and the value is still increasing. Thanks :)

Comment: That's because toast stays for some time and every toast come after previous toast time is over. When you will change it with color logic It'll be fine.

Comment: Well, I tried adapting it to my code, but the issue stands. The color continuously changes only if I make micromovements with my finger while clicking the button. Thanks for trying nonetheless :)